# LaTeX (doubt in image inclusion)

Tags: graphics

When I run a LaTeX file.. I could see the diagram which I have drawn using LaTeX draw but in pdf mode it disappears.. how could I correct this..???  and  in the same way If I use \includegraphics{file} command I could see my image while running but after closing of kile, if I see in dvi or pdf file it disappears..
here is the file..

```
{\centering

\scalebox{.6} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.

{

\begin{pspicture}(-10,-4.145)(10,4)

\definecolor{color43}{rgb}{0.8549019607843137,0.1607843137254902,0.1607843137254902}
\definecolor{color43b}{rgb}{0.8156862745098039,0.12156862745098039,0.12156862745098039}
\definecolor{color46}{rgb}{0.38823529411764707,0.8549019607843137,0.1607843137254902}
\definecolor{color46b}{rgb}{0.12156862745098039,0.8156862745098039,0.2627450980392157}
\definecolor{color49}{rgb}{0.07058823529411765,0.09803921568627451,0.058823529411764705}
\definecolor{color50b}{rgb}{0.06274509803921569,0.21176470588235294,0.09411764705882353}
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](1.3,2.155)(1.34,-4.025)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](0.0,-3.285)(11.92,-3.265)
\pscustom[linewidth=0.04]
{
\newpath
\moveto(0.2,-4.005)
\lineto(0.96,-4.085)
\curveto(1.34,-4.125)(2.37,-4.005)(3.02,-3.845)
\curveto(3.67,-3.685)(4.895,-2.93)(5.47,-2.335)
\curveto(6.045,-1.74)(7.09,-0.395)(7.56,0.355)
\curveto(8.03,1.105)(8.725,2.37)(8.95,2.885)
\curveto(9.175,3.4)(9.43,4.0)(9.46,4.085)
}
\psline[linewidth=0.03cm,linecolor=color43,fillcolor=color43b](3.72,-3.965)(7.04,-0.965)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm,linecolor=color46,fillcolor=color46b](5.2,-3.865)(9.3,3.255)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12,linecolor=color49](7.88,0.795) \psline[linewidth=0.04cm,linecolor=color49,fillcolor=color50b,linestyle=dashed,dash=0.16cm 0.16cm](7.86,0.795)(7.88,-3.225)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12,linecolor=color49](5.26,-2.525)   \psline[linewidth=0.04cm,linecolor=color49,fillcolor=color50b,linestyle=dashed,dash=0.16cm 0.16cm](5.26,-2.525)(5.26,-3.245)
\psdots[dotsize=0.12,linecolor=color49](4.5,-3.285)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\put(-1.514063,-4.1){$x_2$}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\put(-1.15,-4.02){$x_1$}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\put(.6014063,-4){$x_0$}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\put(-.9,-1.14){$Y=f(x)$}
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm,linecolor=color49,fillcolor=color50b,arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.4]{->}(7.4,-0.125)(10.96,-0.165)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm,linecolor=color49,fillcolor=color50b,arrowsize=0.05291667cm 2.0,arrowlength=1.4,arrowinset=0.4]{->}(6.16,-1.845)(11.02,-1.885)
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\put(2.7,-1.8){tangent at $x_0$}
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\put(2.7,-2.92){tangent at $x_1$}
\end{pspicture} 
}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SX site! http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour Thank you for the problem, but it would help us tremendously if you could post your complete code, starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also, please check your submitted text and proof it to your best knowledge. Please use capital letters wheneven appropriate (the beginning of the sentences etc.), try to avoid using letters repeatedly (..., !!!, ??? and similar), the reason is to make reading as pleasant as possible for the real solvers. I know the solution, I will answer your question soon...

Comment: Your problem is that you tried to include postscript picture running {pdf|xe|lua}latex. It doesn't work this way directly. (1) Either you must prepare postscript graphics in a separate file (latex->dvips->ps2pdf->pdfcrop) and load it later, or, (2) use tools like `pst-pdf` and `auto-pst-pdf` are.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be an example of PSTricks picture. Hence you should first obtain *.dvi (`latex` your_file) then *.ps (something like `dvips` your_file)and finally, if PDF is needed, final *.pdf (`pstopdf` your_file).

The programs may have similar, not exactly such names, but the first must be latex, not pdflatex.

Comment: already i did it. but i could not have...@Przemyslaw Scherwentk